# NumberFormatException For input string when try to do a date search in grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I get from the gsp view a string with the date and time:

```
def name = params.name
def time = params.minutes
def date = params.datapicker
```

Now, I want to do a search in my domain by date and name. So, I join the date and time and do the search:

```
def dataSearch = date + " " + time
MyDomain result= MyDomain.findByNameAndDateCreatedGreaterThan(name, dataSearch)
```

But, I'm getting this error:

```
2016-05-26 09:56:44,488 [http-bio-8090-exec-3] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - NumberFormatException occurred when processing request: [POST] /myClass/search- parameters:

name: Bob
minutes: 18:17:42
button: search
datapicker: 2016-04-28
For input string: "2016-04-28 18:17:42". Stacktrace follows:
Message: For input string: "2016-04-28 18:17:42"
    Line | Method
->>   65 | forInputString in java.lang.NumberFormatException
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your `String` to a `Date` before passing it to `findByNameAndDateCreatedGreaterThan`, e.g.

```
def dataSearch = date + " " + time
Date date = Date.parse('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', dataSearch)
MyDomain result = MyDomain.findByNameAndDateCreatedGreaterThan(name, date)
```

Comment: I have a problem with your method: The method build Thu Apr 28 18:17:42 BST 2016 but I need to get this format: "2016-04-28 18:17:42"

Comment: @D.O. If your date is not in the format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` then you'll need to change the format string passed to `Date.parse` to match whatever format you're using. If possible, I would try to change the `params` so that the date is passed in a simpler format, e.g. the day of the week is redundant