# How can cast object 'parseDate' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'java.util.Date' in grails?

Tags: java, datetime, grails

I'm new in grails and I'm trying to parse a String in a java.util.Date with grails. I've read here some questions with the method Date.parse but is deprecated and I want to do it with the new as Date. But, I'm not be able to do it.

Thanks in advance:

```
def date = '2016-05-26'
def minute = '00:00'

def dataSearch = date + minute as Date
```

Comment: Try this answer, is not with as Date, but works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37456277/numberformatexception-for-input-string-when-try-to-do-a-date-search-in-grails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of different `Date.parse` methods, one of which is defined by the JDK and is deprecated, the other is defined by the Groovy JDK and is not deprecated. The deprecated JDK method, takes one argument whereas the Groovy JDK method takes two.

So the short answer is this:

```
Date d = Date.parse('yyyy-MM-dd', '2010-04-03')
```

Comment: Yes, is one solution but it is possible to get the date with only numbers and not with Sat...

Comment: @Simpson a `Date` represents an instant in time independent of any particular representation. I suspect you're confusing the data held within a `Date` with how that data is represented when you call `toString()`.